# JPA 2: Map Mapping fails for duplicate values

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm trying to map a HashMap similar to the one that is specified as example 3 in the JavaDoc for @MapKeyJoinColumn (see http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MapKeyJoinColumn):

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id int studentId;
    ...
    @ManyToMany  // students and courses are also many-many
    @JoinTable(name="ENROLLMENTS",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="SEMESTER"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="COURSE")
    Map<Course, Semester>  enrollment;
    ...
}
```

The generated join table (generated with EclipseLink 2.3) has the following layout:

```
TABLE enrollments (
    student_id bigint NOT NULL,
    semester_id bigint NOT NULL,
    course_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT enrollments_pkey PRIMARY KEY (student_id, semester_id)
)
```

Why is the primary key generated for Student and Semester and not for Student and Course? This doesn't make any sense in this case. With this primary key, a Student can participate in only one course per semester. 'student_id' and 'course_id' should be defined as primary key! This would also match the Java map definition (the key must be unique, but the same value may be assigned to different keys)

Answer (score 0):

JPA sees the relationship as being between Student and Semester, as in a traditional @ManyToMany without the @MapKeyJoinColumn, and in traditional @ManyToMany duplicates would not be allowed, and the items are deleted by source/target ids, so the pk/index is desired to be on these.

For a finer level of control of the model, consider mapping the ENROLLMENTS table to an Enrollment Entity instead.

I can see from the Java model how you may desire different, so please log a bug/enhancement for this.